# Microsoft Graph API - Can't fetch group members of contact type

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a group that contains group, user and contact as members. I can fetch all of them in Admin UI and via PowerShell command `Get-DistributionGroup -Identity 'myGroup'`. Result looks like

```
[{
        "Alias": "xxxxxx",
        "Guid": "xxxxxx",
        "Identity": "xxxxx",
        "PrimarySmtpAddress": "xxxxxx",
        "RecipientType": "UserMailbox",
        "SamAccountName": "xxxxxxx",
        "WindowsLiveID": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "Alias": "yyyyyyyyy",
        "Guid": "yyyyyyyyy",
        "Identity": "yyyyyyyyy",
        "PrimarySmtpAddress": "yyyyyyyyy",
        "RecipientType": "MailUniversalSecurityGroup",
        "SamAccountName": "yyyyyyyyy",
        "WindowsLiveID": ""
    },
    {
        "Alias": "zzzzzzzzzz",
        "Guid": "zzzzzzzzzz",
        "Identity": "zzzzzzzzzz",
        "PrimarySmtpAddress": "zzzzzzzzzz",
        "RecipientType": "MailContact",
        "SamAccountName": "",
        "WindowsLiveID": ""
    }
]
```

[Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members) states that `GET /groups/{id}/members` should return all group members, including users, contacts, and other groups as members.

I get only user and group tyro members back, not mail contact is returned.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [{
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "xxxxxx",
            ........
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
            "id": "yyyyyyyyy",
            ........
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this a bug in API or documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `/v1.0` endpoint does not support Contacts. Since it isn't aware of Contacts, it isn't capable of returning them via `/members`.

The `/beta` endpoint has support for the `microsoft.graph.orgContact` entity. If you switch to this version, you should start seeing Contact members showing up in the results.

This is documented in the Known Issues but it's a little hidden. It isn't filed under Groups but instead under Contacts: [Organization contacts available in only beta](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#contacts).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works in the beta. Where can I find the schedule of this functionality migrating to the main v1.0 API?